# changeLog.internalDelegator [GenericEntity.get] "internalDelegator" is not a field of ChangeGroup

Tags: jira, listener, atlassian-sourcetree, atlassian-plugin-sdk, scriptrunner-for-jira

I am writing some scriptrunner listener code in Jira to be triggered when an issue of type impediment is updated and here is my code:

```
    import com.atlassian.event.Event
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericValue;
import org.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericEntity;

import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor;
import com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.AbstractIssueEventListener;
import com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.IssueEvent;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.ModifiedValue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.util.DefaultIssueChangeHolder;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.util.IssueChangeHolder;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericValue;

def log = Logger.getLogger("atlassian-jira.log")
log.warn("Start Auto Defaults Listener");
log.warn("IssueMounaEvent = " + event); 
Issue issue = event.getIssue();
log.warn("IssueMouna = " + issue);

if (issue.getIssueType().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Impediment")) 
{
log.warn("Analyzing IMPEDIMENT changelog Mouna ...");
event2= (IssueEvent) event; 
def warning = analyzeImpedimentChangeLog(event2);

}




def analyzeImpedimentChangeLog(IssueEvent event) {
def warning = "";
log.warn("IMPEDIMENT STATUS ")
List<GenericValue> changeItems = null;
def impedimentStatus = event.getIssue().getStatus().getName();
log.warn("IMPEDIMENT STATUS "+impedimentStatus)
if (!"New".equalsIgnoreCase(impedimentStatus) && !"Inspecting".equalsIgnoreCase(impedimentStatus)) {

GenericValue changeLog = event.getChangeLog();
log.warn("HERE 1")

HashMap<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<String,Object>();
log.warn("HERE 2")

fields.put("group", changeLog.get("id"));
log.warn("HERE 3")

String author = changeLog.getString("author");
log.warn("HERE 4")
try{

log.warn("CHANGE LOG: "+changeLog.internalDelegator)

changeItems = changeLog.internalDelegator.findByAnd("ChangeItem", fields); 
log.warn("HERE 5")
}catch(Exception e){
log.warn("EXCEPTIONMOUNA "+e)
}

}

return warning;
}
```

I receive the following error, which is kind of weird because this was previously implemented in Java and it worked fine:

```
2022-08-11 EXCEPTIONMOUNA java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [GenericEntity.get] "internalDelegator" is not a field of ChangeGroup
```

I would like to execute the following line of code:

```
changeItems = changeLog.internalDelegator.findByAnd("ChangeItem", fields);
```

and I receive the exception above when writing the following line of code into the log:

```
log.warn("CHANGE LOG: "+changeLog.internalDelegator)
```

This code was previously implemented as a Java plugin and it worked fine in this way. What needs to be done in this case in order to adapt this statement to groovy in ScriptRunner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to access the log, this one:

```
import com.atlassian.event.Event
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericValue;
import org.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericEntity; 
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor;
import com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.AbstractIssueEventListener;
import com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.IssueEvent;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.ModifiedValue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.util.DefaultIssueChangeHolder;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.util.IssueChangeHolder;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericValue;
import org.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericDelegator; 
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.changehistory.ChangeHistoryManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.history.ChangeItemBean;
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.comments.Comment
import com.atlassian.jira.workflow.JiraWorkflow
import com.atlassian.jira.workflow.WorkflowManager
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.changehistory.ChangeHistoryItem
def log = Logger.getLogger("atlassian-jira.log")
log.warn("Start Auto Defaults Listener");
log.warn("IssueMounaEvent = " + event); 
Issue issue = event.getIssue();
log.warn("IssueMouna = " + issue);

            if (issue.getIssueType().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Impediment")) 
            {
                log.warn("Analyzing IMPEDIMENT changelog Mouna ...");
                event2= (IssueEvent) event; 
                def warning = analyzeImpedimentChangeLog(event2);
                if (!warning.isEmpty()) {
                    log.warn("Set IMPEDIMENT warning tooo Mouna " + warning);
                    setWarning(issue, warning);
                }
                else {
                    log.warn("No IMPEDIMENT warning");
                }
            }
            
    


def analyzeImpedimentChangeLog(IssueEvent event) {
            String warning = "";
            log.warn("IMPEDIMENT STATUS ")
            //List<GenericValue> changeItems = null;
            def impedimentStatus = event.getIssue().getStatus().getName();
            // status New and Inspecting are out of scope
            log.warn("IMPEDIMENT STATUS "+impedimentStatus)
            if (!"New".equalsIgnoreCase(impedimentStatus) && !"Inspecting".equalsIgnoreCase(impedimentStatus)) {

                GenericValue changeLog = event.getChangeLog();
                log.warn("HERE 1")

                HashMap<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                log.warn("HERE 2")

                fields.put("group", changeLog.get("id"));
                log.warn("HERE 3")

                String author = changeLog.getString("author");
                log.warn("HERE 4")
                
                //changeItems = changeLog.internalDelegator.findByAnd("ChangeItem", fields);
                
                log.warn("CHANGE LOG: "+changeLog.get("issue"))
                List<GenericValue> changeItems = ComponentAccessor.getChangeHistoryManager().getAllChangeItems(issue)

              //  changeItems = changeLog.internalDelegator.findByAnd("ChangeItem", fields); 
                //changeItems = changeLog
                log.warn("HERE 5::: "+ changeItems)
                log.warn("MOUNA IS HERE AFTER HERE 5 " +changeItems.size());
                log.warn("VALUES 1");

            int lastIndex= changeItems.size()-1; 
            log.warn("MOUNA IS HERE AFTER HERE 5 " +changeItems.size()+ " "+changeItems.get(lastIndex));

            ChangeHistoryItem value= changeItems.get(lastIndex) as ChangeHistoryItem; 
            log.warn("GENERIC VALUE "+ value.getField());

            String modifiedField=value.getField(); 

            if(modifiedField.equals("Source Type") ||modifiedField.equals("Class")||
            modifiedField.equals("Planning Required")){


            log.warn("MOUNA SIZE");
            def ChangeHistoryManager= ComponentAccessor.getChangeHistoryManager();

            List<ChangeItemBean> fieldchangeItems = ChangeHistoryManager.getChangeItemsForField(issue, modifiedField)
            if (fieldchangeItems.size()>0) {
            log.warn("MOUNA FIRST "+ modifiedField);

            //String content = transientVars['Source Type'] as String
            
            def customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager()
            def newStringCf = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName(modifiedField)
            String newString = issue.getCustomFieldValue(newStringCf) as String

            log.warn("MOUNA FIRST "+ newString);

            //def val=cfValues['Source Type']?.value 

            //log.warn(sourceType+" MOUNA FIRST "+sourceTypechangeItems.get(sourceTypechangeItems.size()-1).getFromString());
             String oldString = fieldchangeItems.get(fieldchangeItems.size()-1).getFromString(); 
             warning = "Field \"" + modifiedField + "\" has been changed from \"" + oldString + "\" to \"" + newString + "\" by \"" + author + "\"";
            log.warn("MOUNA FIRST "+warning);


}

            }
                changeItems.eachWithIndex { item, index ->
                    log.warn("ITEM MOUNA "+item);
                    


                
                }
                            
            
            }
        log.warn("changeitemlog== "+warning);

        return warning;
    }

    void setWarning(Issue mutableIssue, String warning)
    {
            log.warn("WARNING FUNC "+warning)

             Warning = 13593
            CustomField customField = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObject(new Long(13593));
            IssueChangeHolder issueChangeHolder = new DefaultIssueChangeHolder();
            customField.updateValue(null, mutableIssue, new ModifiedValue(mutableIssue.getCustomFieldValue(customField), warning), issueChangeHolder);
    
    }
```